# How is this *not* a correct expansion of $\ln(x)$?

Tags: calculus, power-series

I was considering several ways to expand $\ln(x)$ and related logarithmic expressions. Particularly, I had trouble when using the fact that $\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum x^n$. Consider the following reasoning.

1. $\ln x = \ln (u-1)$ with $u=x+1$. Also, $\frac{d}{du}\ln(u-1)=\frac{1}{u-1}=-\frac{1}{1-u}=-\sum_{n \geq 0} u^n$.
2. $\ln(u-1)= \int -\sum_{n\geq0}u^n du = - \sum_{n\geq1}\frac{u^n}{n}$
3. $\ln(x)= -\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(x+1)^n}{n}$.

This expansion is incorrect according to [the result obtained via WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=expand%20ln%5C%2840%29x%5C%2841%29%20to%20order%205). In fact, I obtained different results when making the substitution $u=x-1$ with $\ln x=\ln(u+1)$. Where's the error in the procedure above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equality
$$\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n$$
only holds for $|x|\lt 1$.

So if you want to substitute $\frac{1}{1-u}$ with $\sum u^n$, you must have $|u|\lt 1$.

But if $-1\lt u \lt 1$, then that means that $-2\lt u-1\lt 0$.

And in that case, you cannot *also* consider $\ln(u-1)$, because $u-1$ lies outside the domain of the logarithm.

So either you consider $\ln(u-1)$, or else you take $\frac{1}{1-u}=\sum u^n$, but you cannot do *both*.

By contrast, when you took $u=x-1$ and considered $\ln(u+1)$, you presumably used
$$\frac{d}{dx}\ln(u+1) = \frac{1}{1-(-u)} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-u)^n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nu^n.$$
Here, you still need $|u|\lt 1$, but now you have $-1\lt u\lt 1$, hence $0\lt u+1\lt 2$, and now $\ln(u+1)$ *does* make sense.

Comment: That was very clear. Thank you.